# I need help getting JavaFX to work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I downloaded the java sdk again (like it says here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html )
but JavaFX isn't showing up when I right click on a project. (if it matters i am using the scala plugin on eclipse)

I went here: http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html
but got stuck at step 4/5 where it tells me 'the installation cannot be completed as requested"

then it says:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Kepler 0.9.0.201401250805 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.all.kepler.feature.feature.group 0.9.0.201401250805)

Missing requirement: e(fx)clipse - IDE - FXGraph 0.9.0.201401250805 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxgraph.feature.feature.group 0.9.0.201401250805) requires 'org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group 2.5.0' but it could not be found

Cannot satisfy dependency: From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Kepler 0.9.0.201401250805 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.all.kepler.feature.feature.group 0.9.0.201401250805) To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxgraph.feature.feature.group [0.9.0.201401250805]

what do i need to do to get it to work?

Comment: Which version of JDK have you installed ? The plugin might has a dependency on the [xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/download.html) which is not present in your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the page is pointing to the 0.9.0 release (we released 1.0 on Friday). You now need at least Luna. Simply download http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html